# Can't retrieve req body from api - undefined

Tags: javascript, express

Been stuck on this over an hour or two now >.<

I am unable to access the request body for the user api. I can get the response 'hi' back using res.send (see screenshot) but not with any req.body values. Email is coming back undefined :/

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Content type is set to json on the postman headers.

**Controller:**

```
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'

const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body
  
    res.send('hi' + email)
    
})

export {authUser}
```

**Route:**

```
import express from 'express'
const router = express.Router()
import { authUser } from '../controllers/userController.js'

router.post('/login', authUser)

export default router
```

[image]

hiundefined ^

**Server.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import connectDB from './config/db.js'
import productRoutes from './routes/productRoutes.js'
import userRoutes from './routes/userRoutes.js'
import colours from 'colours'
import { notFound, errorHandler} from './middleware/errorMiddleware.js'

dotenv.config()

connectDB()

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('API is running...')
})

app.use('/api/products/', productRoutes)
app.use('/api/users/', userRoutes)

app.use(notFound)
app.use(errorHandler)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(
    PORT,
    console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold)
)
```

**Headers:**
[image]

Comment: I just tested with your code, copy-pasted out, and it's working fine. Are you 100% sure content type is set to `application/json`?

Comment: I am lost lol. I added the headers to the original post they are set to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this middleware because if you are using Express 4.16+ you can `app.use(express.json())`

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
```

and update your header request accept `Content-Length` : `<calculated when request is sent>`
``
[image]

Comment: Still getting an empty object after using this middleware! >.<

Comment: I tested your code, every things is correct, and I can get email and address, why in the second photo, body is {}?

Comment: your request is incorrect, send content-length

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to pass the request `req` through to your authUser function

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  authUser(req, res)
});
```

Comment: That's being done on this line: `router.post('/login', authUser)`